# NSDateformatter issue for converting date from string

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am getting the date string from the server as `2012-06-21 18:13:33 -04:00`

- What is the correct date format to be set for dateformatter to retrive date from string.
- I had tried using format `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];`
  but I am getting nil in return.

Comment: ya plz help me for the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014858/nsdateformatter-wrong-output-with-string-from-stringwithdate
Same problem?

Comment: hi xapslock i tried that solution also but still not getting the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one suggested by Paul de Lange won't work. This is the reason:
[iPhone NSDateFormatter Timezone Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094730/iphone-nsdateformatter-timezone-conversion)

In short, you will have to change your source data because this is a non-standard format.

Comment: ya i followed the same to change the source data

Comment: Isn't it just RFC 822 format? He isn't using the same format as that linked answer...

Comment: It's very similar but not exactly - It has a colon but no timezone identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html) says you can use 1..3 Z. So how about this one:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
```